# Get the value in entry field then reflect/react to a label in xamarin form

Tags: xamarin.forms

My problem is idk how to reflect in a label depending of input value in a entry field by a customer.
To make the things clear, let's start in our database.
[Our database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHb8k.png)
Few information about our realtime database.
In our DELIVERY TABLE, we have 3 types of delivery(standard, reservation and express). In express, by the word itself, it's a rush delivery and we will require a DELIVERY FEE from the customer.

Another table is PRODUCT. We have 2 product for now, MINERAL(PROD1) AND SPARKLING(PROD2). The price of PROD1 is 35 ana PROD2 is 40.

What I've try right now is I put an SelectedIndexChanged in my picker delivery type and picker product type.
//This is my deliverytype event

```
private async void Picker_DeliveryType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DELIVERY deliverySave = Picker_DeliveryType.SelectedItem as DELIVERY;
            var selectedDeliveryItem = deliverySave.deliveryType;
            var note = deliverySave.deliveryFee;
            
            if(selectedDeliveryItem == "Express")
            {
                
                await DisplayAlert("Note", "Estimated Delivery: 2 hours from now", "OK");
                labelDeliveryFee.Text = "Delivery Fee:" + note;
                entryfieldReservationDate.IsEnabled = false;
               
            }
            else if(selectedDeliveryItem == "Standard")
            {
               
                await DisplayAlert("Note", "Within the day", "OK");
                entryfieldReservationDate.IsEnabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Note", "Enter Reservation Date", "OK");
                entryfieldReservationDate.IsEnabled = true;
            }
          
        }
```

//This is my product type event

```
  private void Picker_ProductType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
            PRODUCT prod = Picker_ProductType.SelectedItem as PRODUCT;
            var selectedProductItem = prod.productType;
            var productPricing = prod.productPrice;

            if (selectedProductItem == "Mineral")
            {
                labelProductPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(productPricing);
            }
            else
            {
                labelProductPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(productPricing);
            }
        }
```

AND my expected output is I want the 2 SelectedIndexChanged will put inside my order button.
//this is my order button click functio now

```
async private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          
            if (selectedDeliveryType == "Standard")
            {
                if (selectedProductItem == "Mineral")
                {
                   //some code here
                    waterOrder.orderTotalAmount = totalprice;
                }
                else
                {
                 //some code here
                    waterOrder.orderTotalAmount = totalprice;
                }
            }
            else if (selectedDeliveryType == "Reservation")
            {
                if (selectedProductItem == "Mineral")
                {
                   //some code here
                    waterOrder.orderTotalAmount = totalprice;
                }
                else
                {
                   //some code here
                    waterOrder.orderTotalAmount = totalprice;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                int deliveryfee = deliverySave.deliveryFee;
                if (selectedProductItem == "Mineral")
                {
                  //some code here
                    waterOrder.orderTotalAmount = totalprice;
                }
                else
                {
                   //some code here
                    waterOrder.orderTotalAmount = totalprice;
                }

            }

            //some code here
            var SaveData = await waterorderRepos.Save(waterOrder);
        
            var SaveDataToCustomerNotification = await waterorderRepos.SaveCustomerNotification(customerNotification);
            if (SaveData)
            {
                await this.DisplayAlert("Order", "Order successfully", "OK");
                ClearData();
                CloseAllPopup();
                return;

            }
            else
            {
                await this.DisplayAlert("Order", "We cannot process your order at the moment.", "OK");
            }

        }
```

I will show you some visual presentation between my work now and my expected output.
[This is the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ro8kT.png)

Please help me guys, idk how to it.Also, no MVVM please cause IDK how to do it. Thank you so much.

Comment: if you want to reference variables from multiple places in your code, declare them as class level variables instead of declaring them locally inside your methods

Comment: do you have any link about your comment sir? Im just newbie in xamarin.

Comment: variable scoping is a basic C# concept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the complexity of your code, I recommend that you use the MVVM pattern for implementation.
I created a demo and achieved your function.

You can refer to the following code:

1.create a view model `MyViewModel.cs`

```
public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Delivery> Deliveries { get; set; }

        private Delivery _deliverySelectedItem;
        public Delivery DeliverySelectedItem
        {
            get => _deliverySelectedItem;
            set { 

                SetProperty(ref _deliverySelectedItem, value);

                // update the TotalAmount
                caculateTotalAmount();

            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
        //add SelectedItem here
        private Product _productSelectedItem;
        public Product ProductSelectedItem
        {
            get => _productSelectedItem;
            set {
                
                SetProperty(ref _productSelectedItem, value);

                // update the TotalAmount
                caculateTotalAmount();

            }
        }


        private int _quantity;
        public int Quantity
        {
            get => _quantity;
            set
            {

                SetProperty(ref _quantity, value);

                // update the TotalAmount
                caculateTotalAmount();
            }
        }

        private int _totalAmount;
        public int TotalAmount
        {
            get => _totalAmount;
            set
            {

                SetProperty(ref _totalAmount, value);
            }
        }


        private void caculateTotalAmount() {

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Quantity.ToString() )  || Quantity == 0) {
                TotalAmount = 0;

                return;
            }

            if (ProductSelectedItem!=null  && DeliverySelectedItem!=null) {

                TotalAmount = ProductSelectedItem.productPrice * Quantity + DeliverySelectedItem.deliveryFee;
            }
        }


        public MyViewModel() {

            Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
            Products.Add(new Product { ProductId = 01, productType = "Products", productPrice = 10 });
            Products.Add(new Product { ProductId = 02, productType = "02", productPrice = 12 });
            Products.Add(new Product { ProductId = 03, productType = "Products", productPrice = 13 });
            Products.Add(new Product { ProductId = 04, productType = "Products", productPrice = 15 });


            Deliveries = new ObservableCollection<Delivery>();
            Deliveries.Add(new Delivery {  deliveryFee = 10, deliveryType = "Express" });
            Deliveries.Add(new Delivery { deliveryFee = 20, deliveryType = "Standard" });
            Deliveries.Add(new Delivery { deliveryFee = 30, deliveryType = "Standard" });


        }

        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;

            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    }
```

2.create class `Delivery.cs` and `Product.cs`

```
public class Delivery 
{
    public string deliveryType { get; set; }

    public int deliveryFee { get; set;}
}

public class Product 
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string productType { get; set; }
    public int productPrice { get; set; }
}
```

3.`MainPage.xaml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:pickerapp2023112="clr-namespace:PickerApp2023112"
             x:Class="PickerApp2023112.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <pickerapp2023112:MyViewModel></pickerapp2023112:MyViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <StackLayout>
        <Picker x:Name="Picker_DeliveryType"  ItemsSource="{Binding Deliveries}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding deliveryFee}"  SelectedItem="{Binding DeliverySelectedItem}"
        Title="Select a delivery type"
        TitleColor="Red">

        </Picker>

        <Picker x:Name="Picker_ProductType"  ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding productPrice}" SelectedItem="{Binding ProductSelectedItem}"
        Title="Select a product type"
        TitleColor="Red">

        </Picker>

        <StackLayout  Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label  Text="Please input quantity: "  BackgroundColor="CadetBlue"/>

            <Entry Placeholder="0"  Text="{Binding Quantity}" TextColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Entry>

        </StackLayout>



        <Label  x:Name="labelDeliveryFee" Text="{Binding DeliverySelectedItem.deliveryFee,StringFormat='The delivery free is {0:F1}'}"    HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Yellow"></Label>

        <Label  x:Name="labelProductPrice" Text="{Binding ProductSelectedItem.productPrice,StringFormat='The product price is {0:F2}'}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Yellow"></Label>

        <StackLayout  Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label  Text="The total amount: "  BackgroundColor="CadetBlue"/>

            <Entry Placeholder="0"  Text="{Binding TotalAmount}" TextColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Entry>

        </StackLayout>

    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**Note:**

1.I add two objects for the `SelectedItem` property of two Pickers and implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`  for this ViewModel, if we change the value of the property, the UI will update automatically. The same is true for other properties.

```
    private Delivery _deliverySelectedItem;
    public Delivery DeliverySelectedItem
    {
        get => _deliverySelectedItem;
        set { 

            SetProperty(ref _deliverySelectedItem, value);
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    //add SelectedItem here
    private Product _productSelectedItem;
    public Product ProductSelectedItem
    {
        get => _productSelectedItem;
        set {
            
            SetProperty(ref _productSelectedItem, value);

        }
    }
```

In this condition, we don't need add event `SelectedIndexChanged`  for Picker.

Comment: Thank you sir, I will try to understand your solution and I will look where I insert the code in retrieving from firebase.

Comment: Hello sir, in you  public MyViewModel(), can I replace that into this code? https://codeshare.io/1YzZ7q

please see the link thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can initialize the value in the constructor of your viewmodel.

Comment: ok sir, I will try that one sir.